# { useTranslation } from "react-i18next" library don't work

Tags: reactjs

```
enter code here
```

Compiled with problems:X

ERROR

[eslint]
src\Components\menu.js
Line 20:25:  React Hook "useTranslation" is called in function "menu" that is neither a React function component nor a custom React Hook function. React component names must start with an uppercase letter. React Hook names must start with the word "use"  react-hooks/rules-of-hooks
Line 20:25:  'useTranslation' is not defined                                                                                                                                                                                                                   no-undef

Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.

```
import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';
import { FaBeer } from 'react-icons/fa';
import { RiStore2Line, RiApps2Line, RiWallet3Line, RiPulseLine } from "react-icons/ri";
import { FaUsersCog } from "react-icons/fa";
import './menu.scss'

import { BsCashStack,BsCreditCard2Back } from "react-icons/bs";
// get url path and set active class
const active = (path) => {
    if (path in window.location.pathname) {
        return 'active';
    }
    return '';
}



const menu = () => {

    const { t, i18n } = useTranslation();
    
    
    return <div className="menuP">

        <div className="menu">
            <NavLink to={'/admin/dashboard'} className={active+' dashboard'}>
                <RiStore2Line size={28} /> <span>dashboard</span>
            </NavLink>
            <NavLink to={'/admin/project'} className={active+' project'}>
                <RiWallet3Line size={28} /> <span>project</span>
            </NavLink>
            <NavLink to={'/admin/category'} className={active+' category'}>
                <RiApps2Line size={28} /> <span>category</span>
            </NavLink>
            <NavLink to={'/admin/user'} className={active+' user'}>
                <FaUsersCog size={28} /> <span>users</span>
            </NavLink>
        </div> 
    </div>
}


export default menu;
```

header

```
import './Header.scss'
import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';
import React, { useContext } from 'react';
import { GoogleLogout } from 'react-google-login';
import { ThemeContext } from '../App';
import { BsCashStack,BsCreditCard2Back } from "react-icons/bs";
import { useTranslation } from "react-i18next";

const Header = () => {
  const Theme = useContext(ThemeContext);
  const clientId = "401-yb.apps.googleusercontent.com";
  // logout function 
  const logout = () => {
    Theme.setUser(null);
    localStorage.removeItem('user');
  }
  const { t, i18n } = useTranslation();
  const changeLanguage = (lng) => {
    i18n.changeLanguage(lng);
  }

  return (
    <header>
      <NavLink to={'/'} className="logo">
        Shop
      </NavLink>
      <div className="menu">
        <nav> 
          <button className="btn btn-primary" onClick={() => changeLanguage('en')}>English</button>
                  <button className="btn btn-primary" onClick={() => changeLanguage('ar')}>Arabic</button>
          <div className="fext">
            {
              // if user is admin show admin menu
              Theme.user != null && Theme.user.isAdmin === true ?
                <div className="admin">
                  <NavLink to={'/admin/dashboard'} className='dashboard'><span>&#9999;</span> <p>{t("dashboard")}</p></NavLink>
                  <NavLink to={'/admin/bill'} className='bill'><span>&#9999;</span> <p>{t('bill')}</p></NavLink>
                  <NavLink to={'/admin/customer'}><span><BsCreditCard2Back/></span> <p>{t('customer')}</p></NavLink>
                  <NavLink to={'/casher'}><span><BsCashStack/></span> <p>{t('cashier')}</p></NavLink>
                </div>
                : null
            }
            <NavLink to={'/cart'}> <img src="/cart.png" alt="" /> <span className='cartN'>{Theme.cart.reduce((total, item) => total + item.quantity, 0)}</span></NavLink>
          </div></nav>
      </div>

    </header>
  )
}

export default Header
```

Comment: `is called in function "menu"` The lint rule uses naming conventions to tell what is a component and what is not. Write your component with a capital letter, ie `Menu`. `'useTranslation' is not defined` Sounds like you havn't imported it. Show us the code if you want better feedback.

Comment: Show the code. It's relevant.

Comment: code now show it

Comment: Have you tried to change `menu` to `Menu` as proposed by @Nicholas Tower?

Comment: Now that we can see the code, my feedback is the same: Rename the component to `Menu`, and import `useTranslation` in the first file (like you did in the second file)